# DDD: naming convention for Representation Layer and Domain Layer classes

Tags: java, rest, domain-driven-design, representation

I apologize in advance because this question is almost a bit silly.  Nonetheless, I can't come up with a good solution myself, so I thought it still worthwhile to ask.

What does one do when the Representation object and the Domain object should have the same name?  The [DDD Sample](http://dddsample.sourceforge.net/) doesn't really address the representation layer, so I was unable to find help there.  An Account class works as well as any to illustrate:

```
package com.mycompany.myproduct.representation;

public class Account {
    private String uuid;
    private String accountNumber;
    // etc

    @JsonCreator
    public Account(@JsonProperty('uuid) String ....
}
```

Maybe this system has a convention to return data as a String whenever possible.  But I like having all the Json annotations here.  While that means XML isn't really supported, that seems okay for now, though more flexibility there would be nice.  Then in the Domain layer there might be another class like this:

```
package com.mycompany.myproduct.domain.model;

import java.uti.UUID;

public class Account extends Entity {
    private UUID id;
    private BigDecimal accountNumber;
    // ... business logic, etc
}
```

If both of these datatypes are named the same the code will be ugly/unsupportable in the cases where they eventually have to meet.  As part of the Ubiquitous Language, it seems like the Domain Layer HAS to have the Account Class.  But the outside world talks in terms of the representation object.  If that is their language, why should they use anything different?

Comment: Are you sure there is a "Representation" layer in DDD? I thought there were only the Interface, Application, Domain, and Infrastructure layers (when following a layered architecture in the first place). Anyway, in your case, I think there would be only one `Account` class, in the Domain layer, and this class can very well have the JSON annotations.

Comment: I wasn't trying to imply that there was such a layer formally in DDD - that is what I meant by saying that there isn't such a layer addressed in the DDD Sample link I included.  That doesn't mean that a REST Representation layer can't be used with DDD though.  I'm asking about what people do in that circumstance.

Comment: I consider metadata annotations such as `@JsonCreator` or JPA's annotations for persistence such as `@Id`, `@Temporal`, etc. to be fine when applied to entities in the domain layer. So, I would use the same class.

Comment: What you are using is a DTO (data transfer object) which is a good choice. I tend not to expose the persistence layer objects. A common patter I see with DTOs is to simply append `DTO` to the class name. I even see people using `Representation`. Personally I generally don't use the same name. It gets confusing

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since these two classes are in separate namespaces, you could keep to the same name.  But as you mentioned, this can get ugly and is certainly misleading.

I strongly advocate for pure, "real-world" naming in your domain layer. Account is a great example.  Your rich `Account` domain entity, with its state, behaviour and invariants, represents an account in the real world.

Identifier naming outside of your domain should perhaps be more explicit to the context in which it is used.  For example, I generally use the following:

- `AccountModel` for an API response model.
- `AccountTable` for a ORM class.
- `AccountDto` for some transfer object (although please do try avoid DTOs!)

Everyone has their own standard.  I believe the important thing to be consistency, especially when you are working with a team.

Comment: I know I dig the very, very old answer, but just curious: why to avoid Dto classes? IMHO they are useful to not expose the domain model to the outside